# Exporting FBX to unreal engine deforms my mesh

Tags: .fbx, unreal-engine

the question is pretty straight, i'm exporting my rigged mesh and the armature to fbx, then i import it from unreal engine and the result is what is shown on the right image, i made some animations in blender and the rig itself is pretty clean, what is causing this issue and how can i solve it?

(The blend file from when i'm exporting the FBX does not have an animation)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue was having shape keys on the mesh, i made a new shape key from mix, set it as the basis and then deleted every shape key, deleting the new shape key as last and that fixed it.